# Equivalent to let expressions in r

Tags: r

Is there some equivalent to express let expressions in r? As an example take this simple haskell code:

```
let x = 1 in x + 1
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: probably, but for those of us unfamiliar with haskell it's difficult to understand exactly what `let` is doing

Comment: It's unclear why you need this but you might be interested in dplyr and its use of magrittr pipes.

Comment: Why would you need something like that in R? Just so `x` is evaluated in that expression only? Sounds like something you can do with environments in R.

Comment: @LyzandeR `local({x <- 1; x + 1})`?

Comment: @Roland Seems like a very good example. Was going to post an example with `new.env()` but `local` is much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are a few:

```
x <- 100

# 1
with(list(x = 1), x + 1)
## [1] 2

# 2
local(x + 1, list(x = 1))
## [1] 2

# 2a
local({
  x <- 1
  x + 1
})
## [1] 2

# 3
eval(substitute(x + 1, list(x = 1)))
## [1] 2

# 4
library(wrapr)
let(c(x = "1"),
  x + 1,
  subsMethod = "stringsubs",
  strict = FALSE)
## [1] 2

x
## [1] 100
```

Also there is an [open issue](https://github.com/zatonovo/lambda.r/issues/24) in the lambda.r package to add `let`.

Answer (score 5):

One equivalent would be a [lambda function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function), which you can define and call in a single statement:

```
(function(x) x+1)(x = 1)
```

The first `()` part defines a function, while the second `()` part calls that function, supplying the value of `1` for the argument named `x`.

Answer (score 3):

If the intent of this is to make `x` only available in that expression, environments could offer this capability:

```
#make an environment
myenv <- new.env()

#assign 1 to variable x in our environment
myenv$x <- 1

#evaluate the expression within our environment
with(myenv, x + 1)
#[1] 2

#x only works within our created environment and not on the global environment 
#(i.e. the default environment when working on the console)
x + 1
#Error: object 'x' not found
```

As per @Roland 's comment this can be shortened to  `local({x <- 1; x + 1})`. See `?local`.

Answer (score 0):

One equivalent is a lambda function, whereby, you use the
implicit `local({ })` within the function body
(this is a slightly improved answer of @ArtemSokolov's answer).

```
(function() {
  x <- 1
  x + 1
})()
```

This is equivalent to

```
local({
  x <- 1
  x + 1
})
```